# Why won't a module installed by `cpanm` be recognized?

Tags: perl, module, perlbrew

I installed perl-5.12.2 using `perlbrew`:

```
perlbrew install perl-5.12.2 -D=usethreads -D=useithreads -D=uselargefiles -f
```

I then switched to this version and installed `IPC::System::Simple` using `cpanm`.

However, when I try to run my script I get:

```
Can't locate IPC/System/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/dave/workspace/proj1/scripts/bin/../lib /home/dave/src/bioperl-live /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.2/lib/site_perl/5.12.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.2/lib/site_perl/5.12.2 /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.2/lib/5.12.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.2/lib/5.12.2 .) at /home/dave/workspace/proj1/scripts/bin/../lib/createLayout.pm line 14.
```

I also found the following dir:
`~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/IPC/System/Simple`
but it's empty (I have no idea if this means something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `which cpanm` from the command line show?  For you it should report:

```
/home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm
```

If thats OK then what does `ls -l /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm` show?  It should be pointing to:

```
cpanm -> /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/current/bin/cpanm
```

And finally `ls -l /Users/barry/perl5/perlbrew/perls/current` should be pointing to the Perl you've switched to in [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/):

```
/home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/current -> perl-5.12.2
```

All three of these must be like this otherwise something is wrong.

If its not then one likely issue is that `cpanm` is pointing to another installed Perl.  You need to have [`cpanm`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/) installed for each version of perl under [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/):

```
perlbrew switch perl-5.12.2
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

Now if `which cpanm` still doesn't show the `perlbrew` path then you have a `$PATH` precedence issue in your `.bash_profile` (or equivalent) file.  This can be fixed by making sure that your [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/) line...

```
source /home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

... in the profile file is after any other `export $PATH` lines.

After re-login back in you can confirm that this is right by doing `echo $PATH` and you should see [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/) at the beginning (the left) of the path string, ie. something like this:

```
/home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:
```

Comment: I failed at your first question. `which cpanm` shows `/usr/bin/cpanm`. I followed the guide CanSpice linked to, and everything went fine **except** that I can't run `cpan-outdated` (as if it's not installed). I think perhaps `cpanm` was not installed correctly (although I did switch before installing it) since I don't even have `/home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/current/bin/cpanm`. However, the third thing seems fine: `/home/dave/perl5/perlbrew/perls/current -> perl-5.12.2`.

Comment: I now note there is a difference between the guide and one of your instructions. compare your `curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus` and the guide's `curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus`. I can't sudo since my user is not in the admin group. Does it mater?  p.s. I can `su`...

Comment: Yes `--sudo` not needed when installing under perlbrew (have edited).

Comment: re: `failed first question`.  Yes everything u've mentioned points to not having `cpanm` installed under your perl 5.12.2 that you installed via `perlbrew` and instead its picking up the `/usr/bin/cpanm` which will be connected to the `/usr/bin/perl` which is the perl it would have installed your `IPC::System::Simple` for (each perl on your machine has its own CPAN directory).

Answer (score 3):

Try [this step-by-step guide](http://blog.fox.geek.nz/2010/09/installing-multiple-perls-with.html), paying close attention to steps 7 and 8 (and optionally 9).

Comment: +1 Thanks. Not solved yet (see my comment to draegtun), but hopefully on the way...